# How to read a text from a text field from c++

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a text field and a button purely designed in c++(without importing a qml doc). How do i read the text from the text field when I click the buton.

I am unable to find a function associated for that.

Comment: Are the button and the textfield QObjects?

Comment: Yes they are inherited by Qobject

Answer (score 3):

To hook up the button to a method, use the following code:

```
button = new Button();
texField = new TextField();

connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onClicked());
```

Then define the `onClicked` slot as so:

```
void ClassName::onClicked() {
    qDebug() << textField->text(); //print the textField's text
}
```

For this to work, this method has to be marked in the class as a `Q_SLOT` and the object itself must be marked as a `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: The question is about QML in which C++ doesn't have direct access to UI elements, so `textField` is not available in the C++ by default.

Comment: Actually, he said that the button was designed in C++.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. The `qml` tag on the question misled me.